# How to redirect home page that do not match any wrong text on url in the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to java, i have developed application with spring boot and spring security. Application working fine but i am facing some vulnerabilities problems.

i.e., after login page goes `http://localhost:8080/login` to `http://localhost:8080/home` page, but when i trying to wrong text in URL like `http://localhost:8080/home` to `http://localhost:8080/sdghgdj` it is throwing `Whitelabel Error Page` but i want redirect to `home` page because session is activ.

What's wrong in my code

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/webjars/**","/assets/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/", "/forgotPwd","/resetPwd","/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/register","/register/**").permitAll()               
            .anyRequest().authenticated()              
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.1. Spring Boot - redirect, for example path `/foo` redirect to `/home` :

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DemoApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/notFound", "/home");
    }


    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> containerCustomizer() {
        return container -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage("/notFound"));
    }

    @RestController
    public static class MyController {

        @GetMapping("/home")
        public String home() {
            return "Hello World";
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

.2. Spring Boot - without redirect, for example path `/foo` will be the same but will be called `@GetMapping("/home")` :

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> containerCustomizer() {
        return container -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage("/home"));
    }

    @RestController
    public static class MyController {

        @GetMapping("/home")
        public String home() {
            return "Hello World";
        }

    }

}
```

[image]